# Unexpected token Error while deploying nextjs app into GCP

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, next.js, deployment

Although i used node.js version 18.13.0, I encountered "Step #2: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'" .
This error occurred by a Nullish_coalescing but I used newer version of Node.js.
In addition, I could deploy my web app in a local PC without errors.
How can I solve this issue? I would appreciate it if you reply it.
Best,
In an app.yaml, I added Node version like below.

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
runtime_config:
  nodejs_version: "18"
entrypoint: npm run start
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 5
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: 'production'
```

Here is error.

```
Step #2: > ai-chatbot-starter@0.1.0 gcp-build /app
Step #2: > next build
Step #2: 
Step #2: /app/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:362
Step #2:                     ...pageKeys.app ?? [], 
Step #2:                                      ^
Step #2: 
Step #2: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
Step #2:     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:16)
Step #2:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:27)
Step #2:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
Step #2:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
Step #2:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
Step #2:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
Step #2:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
Step #2:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-build.js:10:37)
Step #2:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
Step #2:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
Step #2: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Step #2: npm ERR! errno 1
Step #2: npm ERR! ai-chatbot-starter@0.1.0 gcp-build: `next build`
Step #2: npm ERR! Exit status 1
Step #2: npm ERR! 
Step #2: npm ERR! Failed at the ai-chatbot-starter@0.1.0 gcp-build script.
Step #2: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
Step #2: 
Step #2: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Step #2: npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-01-07T01_31_26_023Z-debug.log
Step #2: error building image: error building stage: waiting for process to exit: exit status 1
```

Comment: Please provide more details and format the details correctly in your post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Post the code that matches the error.